# Unable to retrieve countries, providers or devices tag stats from the Mailgun API

Tags: php, mailgun

I am using the mailgun-php library (3.0).

In the example below I am able to retrieve regular stats but the providers list is empty.

var_dump: https://pastebin.com/HAt1JRPy

```
$mgClient = Mailgun::create('key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$stats = $mgClient->tags()->stats($this->mgDomain, 'nbxxx_1125', array(
    "event" => ["accepted","delivered"],
    "resolution" => "month",
    "duration" => "1m"
));

$providers = $mgClient->tags()->providers($this->mgDomain, 'nbxxx_1125');

var_dump($providers);
var_dump($stats);
die();
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
var_dump($providers);
```

try:

```
var_dump($providers->getProviders());
```

and:

```
var_dump($providers->getTag());
```

respectively.

according to:

[public function getProviders(): array](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/272033dff291e25fe592b46f9998376529561c61/src/Model/Tag/ProviderResponse.php#L40)

and:

[$this->assertCount(2, $model->getProviders());](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/6dff17738732069ce2d0bc113ed6d99f3c237e54/tests/Model/Tag/ProviderResponseTest.php#L51)